# Binary Search on specific part of String

Tags: java, string, binary-search, split

This is a string `9*8*0.01548` which is in `ArrayList<String>`. I need binary search based on the `Double` value i.e `0.01548` to find the close match for search value. `ArrayList` contains around 1 million records. `Split` does not seems a good option in terms of optimization.
I tried the following code, though it is not working because the list middle value is calculated based on the list size that is `3`. The binary search itself is fine I just add for clarity of question, if only `Double` values are in `arrayListvalues` then binary search working fine

1. What are the possible alternatives?
2. How to make this working ?

Below is the:

```
public static <T> int binarySearch(List<T> list, T key, Comparator<T> compare) {
int low, high, med, comp;
        T temp;
        high = list.size();
        low = 0;
        med = (high + low) / 2;

        while (high != low + 1) {
            temp = list.get(med);
            comp = compare.compare(temp, key);

            if (comp == 0) {
                return med;
            } else if (comp < 0) {
                low = med;
            } else {
                high = med;
            }

            med = (high + low) / 2;
        }

        return med;
    }
```

Comparator

```
public static class doubleComparator implements Comparator<String> {

 @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            String[] d1 = s1.split("*"); //this
            String[] d2 = s2.split("*"); //that
            if (Double.parseDouble(d1[2]) < Double.parseDouble(d2[2])) {
                return -1;
            } else if (Double.parseDouble(d2 [2]) > Double.parseDouble(d2[2])) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Main

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 ArrayList<String> strArray= new ArrayList<String>();
        strArray.add("1*2*0.1");
        strArray.add("3*4*0.5");
        strArray.add("5*6*0.6");
        strArray.add("7*8*0.7");
        strArray.add("9*10*0.8");
        strArray.add("11*12*0.9");
        int key = binarySearch(strArray, "45*60*0.3", new doubleComparator());
        System.out.println("Search for "45*60*0.3:"\tKey:" + key + "\tValue:" + strArray.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider changing the core element here: why do you want to use an ArrayList with strings; if you will have a million+ entries; and you need to fetch doubles quickly?

Why not do pre-computation: when you fetch your initial records; split them up in two lists; one containing the full string ... the other contains only (already computed and cast) double values? Heck, if the number of objects is not changing; you might even put them in an array (and for a million entries, the cost for array[double] is reasonable smaller than for ArrayList).

Meaning: sometimes it is a waste of time to try to build "efficient" algorithms around poorly represented data. Instead, change the representation of the data so that you can handle it efficiently ...

Of course, this depends on how often ... data changes ... data needs to be (re)computed ... those searches occur. Just saying that you shouldn't be focused on "getting that search right".

Answer (score 1):

Binary search only works for lists, if the elements are ordered by the same property that is searched. Thus the search will only work, **if** the list is sorted by the last value in each `String` (the floating-point value).

Next problem is simply the fact that the relevant value for sorting/searching is the last element of the list, thus making the construction of a `Comparator` for binary-search pretty difficult. Fastest approach (in terms of runtime) would be to build an own loop for the comparison and reorganize the strings in a manner that allows faster comparison. For e.g.: Instead of `"9 * 8 * 0.01548"`, use `"0.01548 * 9 * 8"` to speed the search up.